# Dynamic Programming and the 0/1 knapsack

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm having some trouble understanding dynamic programming, even though I've read through so many resources trying to understand.

I understand an example given of dynamic programming using the fibonacci algorithm. I understand how if you use the divide and conquer approach to it, you'll end up solving some sub-problems multiple times, and dynamic programming takes care of that by solving those overlapping subproblems but only once (and storing them for future reference). However, I have been introduced to dynamic programming in my class using the 0/1 knapsack problem as an example, and I don't really understand the example, or how it illustrates dynamic programming, or how it's in anyway similar to the fibonacci example.

Here are the slides related to it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I mainly understand what is going on until the last slide, where it says f(i,y) = max{....}

What exactly am I finding the max of? Why am I finding the max of anything at all? And most importantly, what does this have to do with dynamic programming? I don't understand the relation, like I do when it comes to the fibonacci example. I honestly have no clue what this knapsack problem has anything to do with dynamic programming because it doesn't even seem comparable in anyway to using the fibonacci example to illustrate dynamic programming. Like I don't see any parallels or anything at all, and it really doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: The max is saying: pick the item or don't, whichever's best.

Comment: these links might be helpful 
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-15-dynamic-programming-longest-common-subsequence/
and http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/

Comment: You should try this: http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/dp_0.swf and http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic programming is just defining the problem in terms of simpler subproblems.

In the case of Fibonacci, we define the problem in terms of the two smaller terms.

In this case, we define the problem with some number of items and some capacity in terms of subproblems containing fewer items and possibly a smaller capacity.

We start off calculating the profit for at most 1 item and every capacity. Then we calculate the profit for at most 2 items and every capacity. Then we do this for at most 3 items, then 4, and so on. Since we've defined one problem in terms of subproblems with fewer items, we can simply look up what we've already calculated to determine any of the values with 2, 3, 4, etc. items.

It might help to think of this as a physical 2D grid, where you fill in the values from one direction to the other, and every time you're only looking in the direction where all the values have already been filled in.

There are overlapping subproblems because in one case we're using the same capacity, and in another we're using a smaller capacity. The smaller capacity is sometimes going to match a different subproblem which was checking the same capacity. That is to say `f(i+1, j)` for one problem is going to equal `f(i+1, y - w_i)` for another problem. As an example, you can see the `f(11, 5)` appears in 2 places:

```
f(10, 8) = max(f(11, 8), f(11, 5) + 77)   // w_i = 3
f(10, 5) = max(f(11, 5), f(11, 2) + 77)
```

In this case we would've already calculated `f(11, X)` for every `X`, so we can just look those values up.

I do find it a bit confusing that we're defining problems in terms of increasing `i`, as in `f(i, j) = ...f(i+1, X)...` and that `f(n, X)` thus contains at most 1 item, instead of using decreasing `i` and having at most 1 item at `f(1, X)`. But this is just semantics and doesn't change the problem in any way.

### Technical details explanations

`f(i,y)` is the maximum profit containing a subset from items `i` through `n` with a capacity of `y`.

Now we can define this as either including or excluding item `i`, and then getting the maximum profit for items `i+1` through `n`.

When we exclude item `i`, this doesn't change the weight, so we can just look at the maximum profit for the same capacity, i.e. `f(i+1, y)`, and the profit also doesn't change.

When we include item `i`, this changes the weight, specifically by the weight of item `i`, which is `w_i`, so we have to look up `f(i+1, y - w_i)`. But then we also get the profit from item `i`, so we need to add its profit, i.e. `p_i`.

Now, since we want the maximum profit, we have to find the maximum of these two values, giving us:

```
f(i, y) = max{f(i+1, j), f(i+1, y - w_i) + p_i}
```

---

If you're still having trouble understanding it, I suggest you construct yourself an example to work through - no amount of explaining quite measures up to seeing it actually working, and using this to get some intuition for why we do things the way we do.

Comment: so when you say that we are defining it in terms of problems containing *less* items and possibly a smaller capacity, in this particular example, it's working backwards from the last item to the first and determining whether item n-1 goes in the knapsack based on what we decided for n, and we determine whether item n-2 goes in based on whether n-1 and n went it, etc? 
Like if for example there are 3 items, we'd first do f(1,y) = max (f (2, y), f(2, y-w_1) + p_1 }, but we wouldn't actually get a profit back until we reached the nth item, and then it'd just work backwards after that? @Dukeling

Comment: is this like recursion where the base case is the nth item and it returns values (or decisions) until it reaches back to the 1st item?

Comment: and if what I just described is correct, would that be an example of using memoization or a "top-down" approach to dynamic programming?

Comment: This is so confusing. I constructed the following example: w = [3, 2, 10] and p = [9, 5, 1], with total capacity being 11 and n= 3 items. So we start with f(n,y), which is f(3, 11)..and because w_3 < y, then f(n,y) = p_n = 1. So what does that mean? The profit of putting it in the knapsack is 1, but we haven't yet decided to put it? so then I'm guessing we go from there to f(2,y) = max {f(3,y), f(3, y-w_2) + p_2 }. So this means the profit of putting 2 is the maximum of the profit of either putting or not putting 3? When we got to f(2,y), is y the value it'd be after adding 3 to the knapsack?

Comment: if I already determined that f(3, y) = 1, then that means for f(2,y) = max {f(3,y) = 1,  f(3, y-w_2)}, but what is y at this point? Is it still the original capacity, 11? I'm really trying to work through it, but obviously I'm having a lot of trouble

Comment: @FrostyStraw: For DP problem its better and simpler to think top-down approach  first which will give you recurrent formula like in this case. this should be easy as Dukeling specified. Now to get Down-Top mechanism that is what DP is you get initial states which contains generally based upon 1 or 2 elements. If you can come to initial condition then you just need to iterate through for successive element with recurrent formula and you are done.

Comment: all these answers are so wrong, @FrostyStraw asked a correct question, where are the overlappping subproblems here ? Overlapping subproblems will only come in when you are rerunning the same algo after storing results after first call right ? As rightly asked by him, in fibonaci, in the first call itself we have overlapping problems but this isn't true in the case of knapsack.

Comment: @codemania23 I added some more details to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*What exactly am I finding the max of?*

f is the sum of the profits brought by all the items that you put in the knapsack. At stage i, there are two possibilities :

- you put item i in the knapsack, and you solve the problem for all remaining items, subtracting the weight of item i from your maximum weight,
- you don't put item i in the knapsack, and you solve the problem for all remaining items. This is a subproblem that you have already solved, since you are working backwards, so the link with dynamic programming should become apparent there.

The solution is the option that brings the highest profit, hence the max.

Comment: how exactly are you working backwards? If you're starting from item i and going to item i + 1, that doesn't seem like going backwards @Zoyd

Comment: The proposed solution works from i = n to i = 1. This is what I called working "backwards", as opposed to recursive algorithms in which the base case is i = 1. I suppose I could have made it more clear. @FrostyStraw

Comment: @Zoyd , please explain where are the overlapping subproblems. ???? I just put it on paper and I don't seem to find any overlapping problems here.